# Prompt coming before print statement when executing a c program in git-bash

Tags: c

```
For example :
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
int i,N;
printf("Enter row no.\n");
scanf("%d",&N);
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
printf("%d\n",i);
return 1;
}
```

In command prompt the execution is in sequence but when I execute this in git bash, first i need to enter the row number then the 'Enter row no' text is displayed followed by the rest of the output of a pattern.
I just dont get why scanf is getting executed before printf in git.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Are you perhaps forgetting the trailing newline in your output in the real code?

Comment: Git is not an execution environment

Answer (score 0):

It isn't. It's just that the `printf` output is *buffered*.

If you want to force the output before `scanf` then *flush* the output buffer:  `fflush(stdout);` will do that.

Comment: `stdout` is typically line buffered. Ther newline at the end should flush it already. Without a MCVE it is not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You could try **defining a macro named "eprint"** to add a **flush()** after calling **printf(...)** and I just use the eprint macro below:

```
#define eprintf(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__); \
                     fflush(stdout);      \
```

---

#### Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define eprintf(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__); \
                     fflush(stdout);      \

int main(void) {
    int a;

    eprintf("a=");

    scanf("%d",&a);

    eprintf("I've read value %d.\n",a);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```